# Laravell, artisan error Class "App\Console\Kernel" does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I have install fresh version of laravel and put inside my script, after that I want to run migrations but there is an error from artisan that class Kernel does not exist when oryginal file in /app/console/Kernel.php exist

error:

```
php artisan

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "App\Console\Kernel" does not exist in /home/john/domains/mydomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:875
Stack trace:
#0 /home/john/domains/mydomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(875): ReflectionClass->__construct()
(...)
#8 /home/john/domains/mydomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(845): Illuminate\Container\Container->make()
#9 /home/john/domains/mydomain.com/artisan(33): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make()
#10 {main}

Next Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [App\Console\Kernel] does not exist. in /home/john/domains/mydomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:877
Stack trace:
#0 /home/john/domains/mydomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(756): Illuminate\Container\Container->build()
(...)
#8 /home/john/domains/mydomain.com/artisan(33): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make()
#9 {main}
  thrown in /home/john/domains/mydomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 877
```

I have check if Kernel file exist, trying to remove vendor folder and composer install but problem still exist

Comment: are you sure you have your packages installed? make sure by running `composer install`

Comment: yes, all installed, reinstalled and problem still appears